# Hyper Ledger Fabric - How to get the name of all organizations (not the peers) of a network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I need that, once an organization is added to the network, my application can get the updated list of all organizations.

I've researched this and the solutions I've found (Discovery Service and Node.js SDK Channel class) only return the name of the peers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Node SDK, at least when using discovery, the `getMspids()` method on the `Channel` returns an array of Member Services Provider IDs:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/Channel.html#getMspids

It may be a bit of work to implement but another approach might be to implement a block listener that inspects blocks as they are committed and looks for config update transactions that include changes to the organizations configured for a network:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.Network.html#addBlockListener